# Android : How to choose the rotation direction of a RotateAnimation?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation

I am currently working on an application in which one I would like to indicate a path with an arrow (it works like a compass).

In order to move the arrow to the good direction, I use the `RotateAnimation` class. It works very well but when the initial degrees position is far from the final degrees position, the rotation does not choose the faster way.

In this video, you can see the behavior : https://youtu.be/vypZni_1s3I

Here the code that is executed when the user click the button "02" :

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(355f, 8f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
test.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Here the code that is executed when the user click the button "03" :

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(8f, 350f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
test.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

As you can see in the video, the rotation does not choose the faster way. In the first animation, the faster way is to have a clockwise rotation (but the system chooses ann anticlockwise rotation) and in the second animation, the faster way is to have an anticlockwise rotation (but the system chooses a clockwise rotation).

Is there a solution or a trick to force the system to choose the faster way in order to rotate from a point A to a point B ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The RotationAnimation object will turn clockwise if the parameter `toDegrees` is greater than the parameter `fromDegrees`. You have to handle yourself the fact that actually, yo do not want to go from `355f` to `8f`, but from `355f` to `368f` (which is 360 degrees plus 8 degrees).

So here you would change your two pieces of code as follows :

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(355f, 368f, 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
test.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

and

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(368f, 350f, 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
test.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

But I would suggest you, if you are willing to create an app using API 14+ to use the `animate()` method of `View` like this :

```
test.animate()
  .rotationBy(13f)
  .setDuration(3000)
  .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
  .start();
```

The `rotationBy(offset)` method will rotate your view - with a central pivot - by `offset` degrees, clockwise if offset is positive, anticlockwise otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

+1 @MaximeClaude's but answer can be greatly shortened:

```
//declarations
private static final int HALF_CIRCLE = 180;
private static final int WHOLE_CIRCLE = 360;
private float currentAzimuth = 0f;

public void rotate(float rotationDegrees, View... views) {
    float from = currentAzimuth;
    float to = rotationDegrees;
    float min = Math.min(from, to);
    if (Maths.abs(to - from) > HALF_CIRCLE) {
        if (min == from) {
            from += WHOLE_CIRCLE;
        } else {
            to += WHOLE_CIRCLE;
        }
    }
    currentAzimuth = rotationDegrees;

    Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(from, to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setFillAfter(true); //make the arrow stay at its destination (after rotation)
    anim.setDuration(200);
    for (View view : views) {
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

And using a `android.view.OrientationEventListener` to set view orientation:

```
mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(context) {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        rotate(orientation, arrowView);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone asking later, this is a general case inspired from @David Fournier's answer:

```
//declarations
    private static final int HALF_CIRCLE = 180;
    private static final int WHOLE_CIRCLE = 360;
    private float azimuth = 0f;
    private float currenttAzimuth = 0f;

    /**
     * "will set rotation from " + currentAzimuth + " to " + azimuth
     */
    public void rotate(Double bearing){
        if(bearing != null) {
            azimuth  = (float)bearing.doubleValue();
            float min = Math.min(azimuth,currenttAzimuth);

            float tempAzimuth = 0.0f;
            float tempCurrentAzimuth = 0.0f;

            Animation rotateAnim = null;
            if(Math.abs(azimuth - currenttAzimuth) > HALF_CIRCLE) {
                if(min == currenttAzimuth) {
                    tempCurrentAzimuth = currenttAzimuth + WHOLE_CIRCLE;
                    tempAzimuth = azimuth;
                }
                else {
                    tempCurrentAzimuth = currenttAzimuth ;
                    tempAzimuth = azimuth + WHOLE_CIRCLE;
                }
                rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(tempCurrentAzimuth, tempAzimuth,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            }
            else {
                rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(currenttAzimuth, azimuth,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            }
            currenttAzimuth = azimuth;
            rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true); //make the arrow stay at its destination (after rotation)
            rotateAnim.setDuration(500);
            arrowView.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrow is rotated to a different way each time. You can choose a different angle. Don't forget the minus angle is also available.

You can use `animate()` like this:

```
if (view==button1) {
            arrowImage.animate().rotation(0).start();
        } else {
            arrowImage.animate().rotation(-90).start();
        }
```